# How can I convert epoch datetime in python?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format, epoch

I'm calling an api and getting the datetime field in this format /Date(1500462505221)/ . My motive is to convert it to this format "2018-05-11 23:25:47" . How do I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use datetime library to make life simple:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.fromtimestamp(1485714600).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S")
```

Comment: I forgot to mention. Is it possible without doing any string operations ? Any library that takes the string as is and converts to datetime ?

Comment: can you give me one example of string which you want to convert in datetime?

Comment: '/Date(1506342842815)/'

Comment: import time

time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',  time.gmtime(1506342842815/1000.))

Comment: So basically I would need to trim off "/Date(" and ")/" ?

Comment: Why you need to trim, you directly give number rather than '/Date(1506342842815)/'.

Answer (score 1):

So here is what i got to convert time in human readable format, maybe this can help:

```
import time
time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z", time.localtime(1500462505221))
```

or

```
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1500462505221))
```

and one more thing i tried this example by removing last three digit of as follows and got this as output:

```
>>time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1500462505))
>>'2017-07-19 11:08:25'
```

You can also refer this link:
[https://www.systutorials.com/241698/how-to-convert-epoch-timestamp-to-human-readable-date-format-in-python/

Comment: Is there any solution without doing any string manipulation/modifications ?

Comment: i tried it without any string modification but that's not working fine. In fact trimming the string would be a good option.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using `time` and `re` modules:

```
import re, time

epoch_str = "/Date(1500462505221)/"
date = re.match(r'/Date\((\d+)\)/', epoch_str).groups()[0]
epoch_fmt = time.strftime('%Y-%M-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(float(date)))
# Or you can do
# date_ = time.gmtime(float(date))
# epoch_fmt = '{}-{}-{} {}:{}:{}'.format(date_.tm_year, date_.tm_mon, date_.tm_mday, date_.tm_hour, date_.tm_min, date_.tm_sec) 
print(epoch_fmt)
# 49517-20-07 04:20:21
```